# Using FileInputStream compile error says variable is uninitialized

Tags: java

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong in the below java code ? It doesn't compile and gives me compilation error.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ShowFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        FileInputStream Fin;

        try {
            Fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cbr\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exp) {
            System.out.println("exception caught" + exp);
        }
        try {

            do {
                i = Fin.read();
                System.out.print((char) i);
            } while (i != -1);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught" + exp);

        }
        finally {
            try {
                Fin.close();
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught" + exp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

while the below code compiles. You can see both initialization are within try block.

```
import java.io.*;

class ShowFile2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin;
// First make sure that a file has been specified.

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cbr\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            return;
        }
        try {
// read bytes until EOF is encountered
            do {
                i = fin.read();
                if (i != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) i);
                }
            } while (i != -1);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        }
        try {
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Error closing file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that if `new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cbr\\Desktop\\test.txt");` throws an exception, your variable will not be initialized in the second part of your method. This is not allowed. Object members will be initialized to `null` when the object is created, but this is not the case for local variables: they must be initialized explicitly.

A quick fix (but read on for a better fix) would be to initialize your variable (to `null`) when you are defining it:

```
FileInputStream fin = null;
```

This will solve your compilation error, however, you will get `NullPointerException`s when an exception is thrown in the first catch block.

A better solution is to put your error handling logic in the same place: if creating the `FileInputStream` fails, you don't want to read bytes from it anyway. So you can use a single try-catch block:

```
try {
    fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cbr\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    // Read bytes from fin.
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
    ...
}
```

Final advice: to make sure that your input stream is closed in all circumstances, you can use a try-with-resources block:

```
try (fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cbr\\Desktop\\test.txt")) {
    // Read bytes from fin.
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does compile because the `ShowFile2` class contains `return` in the catch block: this will ensure that the variable `fin` will be always initialized.

In the first class you caught the exception and you continue the execution of your program.

Comment: Thank you. I see how return is initializing the variable. If there are multiple variables, lets say. does a single `return` do the initialization for all of them ?

Comment: `return`doesn't initialize the variable: it ensure you that if no `FileNotFoundException` will be throw then your code to inizialize the variable will be executed. For more variables you have to ensure to catch every type of exceptions (it could be one, for example, if they are all `FileInputStream` type) and write `return` in every catch block. **Note that this will not ensure you that the inizialization will be corret, but only that the code to inizialize will be executed**